# ERC721. How to add additional information related to property using erc721 standard

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm not having so much experience with ERC721 token standard, currently  I'm working on a real-estate DAPP. I have a question. if I want to add external information related to a specific property like Location, Price, property number etc. every time if a new property register, what will be the best way to do that..?? but I don't want this with solidity Struct, is it possible to extend the `ERC721 Metadata Interface Contract`?? or any other solution??

I have tried almost everything but I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to store the data on-chain, a `mapping (uint256 => Property)`, where the `uint256` is the token ID and `Property` is "struct(location, price, ...)", containing the data is probably the cheapest option gas-wise.

But since your question states you don't want to use struct, you can chose to store the data on-chain with a series of mappings:

```
mapping (uint256 => string) tokenIdToLocation;
mapping (uint256 => uint64) tokenIdToUsdPrice;
// etc.
```

You can also decide to store the data off-chain, and link to this storage from your contract. In that case, you'd implement the `tokenURI()` function of the `ERC721Metadata` interface (both defined in the [ERC-721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md)). The `tokenUri()` would return a (string) URL of an off-chain resource where you can display the (off-chain) data.

Comment: for off-chain, ipfs will solve this, one more doubt i have still is that is there any possibility to extend erx721 metadata?

Comment: Yes, as long as you implement the functions and events defined in the interface, you can also implement other functions (not defined in the interface) and it's still going to be a valid interface implementation.

Comment: as you mentioned above the second way to do that by using mapping for each single field, i think the third off-chain solution will be best, and we just need to store the hashes which is another concern, if i ask you honestly, what will you choose to do the best in this scenario??

Comment: Hashes of what? Of the off-chain content? In that case, I'd use `mapping (uint256 => bytes32) tokenIdToOffchainContentHash;` _(Update the bytes length according to the length of your hash.)_

Comment: and why bytes32??

Comment: As I said, "Update the bytes length according to the length of your hash". 32 bytes was simply the first hash length that came into my mind.

Comment: yeah, it means that the content hash of ipfs will be stored in smart contract, so that's how anyone can verify data on ipfs

Comment: ```mapping (uint256 => bytes32) tokenIdToOffchainContentHash``` uint256 will be tokenId and the bytes32 will be the content hash of ipfs

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post where I finally found a solution. It includes a sample implementation for both ERC20 and ERC721, forked from an implementation of Kaleido's Firefly and amended to cater for the mentioned Real Estate dApp. Hope it helps someone.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/example-adding-custom-data-to-erc20-token-transfer/